# Ask DHCP Over Vlan

Tags: debian

[image]

can some one give clue to send DHCP with this topologi
i use vmware esxi to make this topology

Comment: You can run a "DHCP forwarder" on any subnet that needs DHCP, which forwards the request to a single central DHCP server. Cisco routers have this optn built-in. Then your DHCP server can run multiple zones, assigning different IP pools. ISC dhcpd can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be a router somewhere that routes traffic between vlan 30 (your client) and vlan 20 (your dhcp server).
On this router you must enable DHCP relay (sometimes called DHCP forwarder) to forward DHCP requests from VLAN 30 to your server.
And on the DHCP server you will have to setup a DHCP scope for the subnet you want to be used on vlan 30.

Comment: i dont know its not work
i was use dnsmasq for dhcp reply

Comment: It doesn't matter which software you use for the DHCP server. The ROUTER must forward the DHCP packets. Whitout that it will never work.

Comment: i sue dhcp server isc-dhcp-server and relay use dnsmasq

but in dhcp relay i get error
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use